# How do I create, save, and pass a valid SPTSession once I am logged in Spotify?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, spotify, spotify-app

I'm having trouble with Spotify beta 9.  All the tutorials seem phased out regarding saving a SPTSession and updating(refreshing) with the RefreshTokenURL.  This is how I'm getting the AuthViewController....

```
        let spotifyAuthenticationViewController = SPTAuthViewController.authenticationViewController()
        spotifyAuthenticationViewController.delegate = self
        spotifyAuthenticationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
        spotifyAuthenticationViewController.definesPresentationContext = true
        presentViewController(spotifyAuthenticationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now I need to create a session, save, and periodically refresh.  I would like to save in CoreData.  Please help if you've done this before or have any good tips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to store it in NSUserDefaults:

```
SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];
id sessionData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:auth.sessionUserDefaultsKey];
SPTSession *sessionUserDefault = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:sessionData];

auth.tokenRefreshURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kTokenRefreshServiceURL];

    if (![sessionUserDefault isValid] && [auth hasTokenRefreshService]) {
        [auth renewSession:sessionUserDefault callback:^(NSError *error, SPTSession *renewedSession) {
            if (error != nil)
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"spotifySessionNotOK" object:renewedSession];

            if(renewedSession)
                self.session = renewedSession;

        }];
    }
    else {
        self.session = sessionUserDefault;
    }

  [auth setSessionUserDefaultsKey:auth.sessionUserDefaultsKey];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at time of writing, beta 25 does this automagically for you if you set `auth.sessionUserDefaultKey` when you config your session.

You can then check for a valid session
`(auth.session != nil && auth.session.isValid)`